# Not receiving response from Unofficial Android Market API called for getting installed app information(AppRequest)

Tags: android, api, android-market-filtering

I am new to stackoverflow, so not too much familiar with  posting question on      stackoverflow.

Descrption: I did it with authsubtoken as well as hard coded login credentials but not receiving response ,My app having Min Version - 14 ,max version - 19,library used - androidmarketapi 0.6 , protobuf-java 2.2.0. I used step mention in  below link.

https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

```
 new AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>() {       
                    @Override
                    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        final String android_id = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID); 

                              MarketSession session = new MarketSession();
                              session.login("sagar@gmail.com","*********");
    //                        session.setAuthSubToken(authsubtoken);
                              session.getContext().setAndroidId(android_id);

                              String query = "Demolistview"; //app_name
                              AppsRequest appsRequest = AppsRequest.newBuilder()
                                                              .setAppId("com.playstoreapp")
                                                              .setQuery("Demolistview")
                                                              .setStartIndex(0).setEntriesCount(10)
                                                              .setWithExtendedInfo(true)
                                                              .build();

                              session.append(appsRequest, new Callback<AppsResponse>() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onResult(ResponseContext context, AppsResponse response) {
                                                // Your code here
                                                // response.getApp(0).getCreator() ...
                                                // see AppsResponse class definition for more infos
                                           System.out.println(response.getApp(0).getCreator());
                                           Log.e(TAG,"Developer Name >>" +response.getApp(0).getCreator());    
                                           Log.e(TAG,"Developer Name >>" +response.getApp(1).getPackageName());        
                                           Log.e(TAG,"Developer Name >>" +response.getApp(2).getRatingsCount());        
                                       }
                              });

                              session.flush(); 


                          return null;
```

}

```
        }.execute();
```

Thanks in advance...